# Как остановить рекурсию, не добавляя переменные вне функции

Tags: javascript, extjs

Есть код. В нем реализована рекурсия. Как можно остановить рекурсию, не объявляя переменную за пределами функций? Аналогичный код используется в Extjs. Там неудобно выносить переменную за пределы функций.

```
<script>
    test1();

    function test1() {

        console.log('test1');
        test2()
    }

    function test2() {

        console.log('test2');
        test3()
    }

    function test3(){ 

        console.log('test3');
        test1()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: остановить по какому условию?

Comment: Задача, чтобы данный код сработал один раз - один проход

Comment: убери вызов `test1` из `test3` и все

Comment: в реальности код намного сложнее и test1 в test3 должен быть

Comment: передайте какой нибудь аргумент = boolean в `test1()` и проверяйте если флаг == false то `return;`

Comment: @IosifSerbskiy, тогда стоит привести более реальный пример. Пока убирание вызова из последней функции - самое лучше решение

Comment: К чему такие ограничения?

Answer (score 2):

В JS ф-ция это объект, который может хранить в себе значения. По этому можно сделать что то типо такого:

https://jsfiddle.net/bg4quL5d/

```
function test1() {
  if (test1.isCalled) return false;
  test1.isCalled = true;
  ...
  test1.isCalled = false;
}
```

Данный код не оптимальный, и нужно добавить try - finally чтобы он работал в любой ситуации, но он показывает как именно этим можно воспользоваться .

Как вариант - сделать ф-цию обвертку, которая будет делать тоже самое для удобства чтобы не пихать test1.isCalled = false при каждом return . Так же , если уже делать обвертку то можно и сделать локальный секретный объект чтобы другие ф-ции не могли изменять текущее состояние func1.

Сделал ф-цию, которая обварачивает ф-цию чтобы она вызывалась только один раз. https://jsfiddle.net/9j7urm0m/2/

```
function blockRecur(func) {
   var object = {isCalled: false};
   return function() {
       if (object.isCalled) return;
       object.isCalled = true;
       try {
           return func.apply(null, arguments);
       } catch (e) {
           throw e;
       } finally {
          object.isCalled = false;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    test1();

    function test1(b) {
        if (b == false){
            return;
        }
        console.log('test1');
        test2()
    }

    function test2() {

        console.log('test2');
        test3()
    }

    function test3(){
        var b = false;
        console.log('test3');
        test1(b)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: это равносильно убиранию вызова `test1` из `test3`. Просто с большим количеством кода.